# I can't to open all projects in visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I'm new in Asp.net mvc, and I want to load this project but I can't  see more folder projects in the solution explorer. somebody knows what I must to do?

[this is my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwliG.jpg)

Comment: Can you right click on those projects and reload those?

Comment: Look at the error list or output window, Visual Studio will tell you there why it can't load those projects.

Answer (score -1):

Open your Visual Studio as an Administrator.

Comment: I discovered the problem, apparently my OneDrive added IIS files to my account and it was disabled.